# TFS Gated Check In - Send Email Notification only to the Build Requester if the build fails

Tags: email, continuous-integration, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines, gated-checkin

I am using TFS 2015 for Continuous Integrations and Deployment. I have set up the Gated Check in for my build definition.

**Question**: Is there any way to send an email alerts to the developer who requested the build if the build fails?

[image: Email Notification if the build fails]

I understand that, We have TFS Alerts for sending an email based on the build status but That needs Email addresses to be explicitly specified to send email.

Is there any other option or some keyword which I can mention in the "Send To" field so that I can send the build fail email only to the person who requested the build.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no direct option, developers can subscribe to the TFS custom alerts.

Check This ==> [TFS Alerts and Notifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tSCk.png)

[Refer It](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/alerts-and-notifications) here for more Info